# How to change the namespace prefix color inside XML files in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

I want to change the color of the namespace prefix such `android` `app` `tools` etc.

I opened the settings and I didn't find any option there to change it.!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's under this path: AndroidStudio>Preferences>Editor>Color Scheme>XML> Namespace prefix

Comment: I don't how I didn't see that..! I was looking at the preview block all the time and didn't notice the names above.! thanks for the headsup.!

Comment: it's easy to miss the namespaces shown in the example code below the properties! Glad I could be of help!